# Can not install "posix" package using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I installed Anaconda on my PC (windows), then I tried to run the following:

```
import pdb
import sys
import os
import posix
sys.path.append(os.path.join(posix.environ['HOME'], 'mlprojects', 'swig', 'src'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(posix.environ['HOME'], 'mlprojects', 'datasets', 'python'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(posix.environ['HOME'], 'mlprojects', 'mlopy', 'netlab'))
##ENDSETUP
import ndlml as nl
import ndlwrap as nw
import numpy as np
import datasets
import netlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import matplotlib.mlab as ml
import matplotlib.axes
import math
```

After running the above code, I got the following error:

> ```
> File "C:/Users/yat/test.py", line 9, in <module>
> import posix
> ImportError: No module named posix
> ```

When I tried `pip install posix`, I got the following message:

> ```
> Collecting posix
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement posix (from   versions)
> No matching distribution found for posix`
> ```

How do I install `posix` package, and where to find all installed packages in Anaconda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a built-in module that's not available on Windows. Look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/posix.html):

> **Do not import this module directly.**  Instead, import the module `os`,
>   which provides a *portable* version of this interface.  On Unix, the `os`
>   module provides a superset of the `posix` interface.  On non-Unix operating
>   systems the `posix` module is not available, but a subset is always
>   available through the `os` interface.  Once `os` is imported, there is
>   *no* performance penalty in using it instead of `posix`.  In addition,
>   `os` provides some additional functionality, such as automatically calling
>   `os.putenv` when an entry in `os.environ` is changed.

So just replace `posix` with `os` and you should be good to go.

---

To list all the installed packages with Anaconda, look at [the docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#list-all-packages):

> List all of your packages in the active environment:
>
> ```
> conda list
> ```
>
> To list all of your packages installed into a non-active environment
>   named `snowflakes`:
>
> ```
> conda list -n snowflakes
> ```